# mapreduce fails while reading large number of csv files

Tags: csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I am able to read csv files if i run them individually through mapreduce. But when i run from a folder having n number of files mapreduce job is failing at 100% showing the below error:

```
INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 99% reduce 0%
INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1889843460_0001_m_000190_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map
INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1889843460_0001_m_000190_0' done.
INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1889843460_0001_m_000190_0
INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1889843460_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at com.calsoftlabs.mr.analytics.common.ClientTrafficRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ClientTrafficRecordReader.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1) Always wrap the logic in the mapper's map() method (and the reducer's reduce() method) in a try-catch block so something like this doesn't blow then entire job out of the water

2) In the catch block, you can log the invalid input key/value along with the error or, for development purposes, just write the info to the console.  If you're debugging the job, you can set a breakpoint on the first line of the catch block.

It looks like you have 190 tasks which probably means you have that many small files.  My guess is that one of the later files - one you haven't run through manually- is causing the problem

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with the try-catch point.  A problem that I've had before is "hard coding" how I parse a line (I know a priori there are 3 columns, etc).  Then, I run into issues if one file has an extraneous new line character at the end (that line doesn't have the 3 column form).  A try-catch fixes that.  This is just one of many possibilities for subtle, hard to catch, differences among files that might lead to an issue.

Comment: I dont have that issue because the csv files are generated by us which we are feeding to MR jobs. As said previously individually all files are running fine or even if i give 2 files as input. But when i give the whole directory MR jobs fail. I am thinking its a different problem but please suggest me how i can resolve it.